# Pass List[String] or Seq[String] to groupBy in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`df.groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3")` works perfectly fine.

But when I try to do the following:

```
val dimensions = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")
df.groupBy(dimensions)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
<console>:38: error: overloaded method value groupBy with alternatives:
  (col1: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData
 cannot be applied to (Seq[String])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`*` after argument list denotes varargs so you have to unpack the sequence. If you have as signature like:

```
def foo(ts: T*) = ???
```

it can be called with arbitrary number of arguments of type `T`:

```
foo()
foo(t1)
foo(t2)
...
```

If you have a sequence, you can pass it using `_*` syntax:

```
val ts: Seq[T] = ???
foo(ts: _*)
```

Please refer to [Repeated Parameters section](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters) in Scala Language Specification for details.

So in this case you can either:

```
df.groupBy(dimensions.head, dimensions.tail: _*)
```

to match `(col1: String,cols: String*)`, or

```
df.groupBy(dimensions map col: _*)
```

to match `(cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)`

Comment: The last option `df.groupBy(dimensions map col: _*)` is very helpful - thank you! I saw a trick with ".head" and ".tail" a few times already, but this one is new to me.

Comment: ```df.groupBy(dimensions map col: _*)```. This is new one for me also in terms of syntax. I was using ```df.groupBy(dimensions.map(col): _*)```